# NumberFormatException handling

Tags: java

Could anyone please explain to me why the add() method returns 0 instead 4?
I am trying to use int 0 in case "invalid" string number is provided (e.g. four).
I am getting the right results for String arguments 3,4 / 3,four / three,four / but not for three, 4.

Can you please give me hints what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
public class Numbers2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(add("d","4"));
    } // main() method

   public static int add(String a, String b)
   {
       int x = 0;
       int y = 0;

      try{ 
          x = Integer.parseInt(a); 
          y = Integer.parseInt(b);

          System.out.println("No exception: " + (x+y));

          return x + y;
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e){

          if(x != (int) x ){              
              x = 0;
          }
          if(y != (int) x ){
              y = 0;              
          }      
          return x + y;  
      }

   } // add() method
} // class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the line `y = Integer.parseInt(b);` doesn't get the chance to execute as you are passing `"d"` as the first argument which is not an integer, the line `x = Integer.parseInt(a);` results in exception and both `x` and `y` remain 0.

You could solve the problem by using separate try/catch for both:

```
int x = 0; //x is 0 by default
int y = 0; //y is 0 by default

try { 
    x = Integer.parseInt(a); //x will remain 0 in case of exception  
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {  
    y = Integer.parseInt(b); //y will remain 0 in case of exception  
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}

return x + y; //return the sum
```

Comment: that's exactly it... that's the answer I was looking for... thanks for much!

Answer (score 1):

Because the second argument is "d", you will always fall to the exception case. Here, x = y = 0.

Your If statements here will no do anything, as (x == (int)x) always when x is an int and (y == (int)x) as they are both 0 so neither of these blocks get executed.

Thus, x + y will always = 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you use wrong formate argument as first argument then exception occurs at statement

```
x = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

The line

```
y = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

is never executed in this case, so use different try-catch block for each statement.